# FATAL EXCEPTION ACCESS with JVM

Tags: exception, jvm

Although I have disabled UAC as told to do so by the Java forums it still occurs

http://pastebin.com/SaHmCK4s

I have disabled UAC by regedit too

Comment: The given message is meaningless without full contents of `hs_err_pid.log`.

Comment: All the header tells you is something went wrong, to get some idea you need to read the rest of the log.

Comment: Sorry, here it is. http://pastebin.com/d3KFVREz